# AS3 Snap line to objects

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have a question on how can i make a line to be snapped to the center of an object, in my case i draw some circles when the button is pressed and then another button adds lines but i want them to snap to the center, so when i move the circle the lines extends/compresses the code where i create the circle :

```
function new_sond(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (i<9)
    {
    i++;
    q=i;
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();  
    btn.graphics.beginFill(0x0099FF, 1);
    btn.graphics.drawCircle(400, 300, 15);
    btn.graphics.endFill();
    var s:String = String(q);
    btn.name=s; 
    var textField = new TextField();
    textField.mouseEnabled=false;
    textField.text = i;
    textField.width = 10; 
    textField.height = 17;
    textField.x = 395; // center it horizontally
    textField.y = 292; // center it vertically
    btn.addChild(textField);
    this.addChild(btn);
    }}
```

The code where i draw the line from circle to circle

```
function click1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click1);
    if (e.target.name!=null ){
    cntr=cntr+1;
    trs=e.target.name;
    var trn = Number(trs);
    du[cntr]=trn;
    sx=e.target.x+400;
    sy=e.target.y+300;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click2);
    }
}




function click2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click2);
    fx=e.target.x+400;
    fy=e.target.y+300;
    var i:int;
    i=2;
    trs=e.target.name;
    var trn = Number(trs);
    u[cntr]=trn;
    var  line:Shape = new Shape();
    line.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xFF0000,2);
    line.graphics.moveTo(sx,sy);
    line.graphics.lineTo(fx,fy);
    this.addChild(line);

    var inputField:TextField = new TextField();
    inputField.border = true;
    inputField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    inputField.width = 23;
    inputField.height = 18;
    inputField.x = (sx+fx)/2;
    inputField.y = (sy+fy)/2;
    inputField.multiline = false;
    inputField.maxChars = 3;
    inputField.restrict = "0-9";
    inputField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, checkInput);
    addChild(inputField);
}
```

Sorry for the long post, but i really need some help , i just don`t know how to do it and have no ideas, it is a big project i`m working on for simulating the MaxFlow
how it looks :  http://gyazo.com/d0478d967b4cc34b59490245b3530e26
I just want to know if it is possible to make the lines snap to the center of circles...

Answer (score 1):

After your second click (in which you plot your final point and complete the line), you need to have a step that iterates through all of the objects in which you want to potentially snap to.

Within this aforementioned step, you can calculate and see if the 2nd plot point is within your snap distance of the object and will set that plot point equal to the object's x and y (which should be the center point). If not, it will simply continue through the loop until all snap-able objects have been exhaustively tested.